# Windows error reporting and out of range exceptions

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am observing a similar problem in a much larger program to something that can be replicated with the code below:

```
int main()
{
    printf("starting application");
    std::string str {"This is my string"};
    printf("The last char is %d", (int)(str.at(str.size()))); 
    return 0;
}
```

This obviously crashes with an uncaught `std::range_error`.

To debug this, I have set up Windows Error reporting and as expected it is creating a minidump. However, when I load the minidump into Visual Studio to generate a call stack I get the following:

```
msvcr120.dll!abort() Line 88    C
msvcr120.dll!terminate() Line 96    C++
test2.exe!__CxxUnhandledExceptionFilter(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS * pPtrs) Line 39 C++
KERNELBASE.dll!_UnhandledExceptionFilter@4()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  Unknown
```

which is totally useless in identifying the root cause of the problem.

What I am after is a callstack like:

```
KernelBase.dll!_RaiseException@16() Unknown
[External Code] 
msvcp120.dll!std::_Xout_of_range(const char * _Message) Line 24 C++
test2.exe!main() Line 16    C++
[External Code]
```

(when running with a debugger)
Which identifies the place that the std::range_error occurred. Does anyone know how to configure Windows Error Reporting so it does not hide the error as it does in the top callstack?

I am Using Visual Studio 2013 on Linux using g++. The application core dumps and when the core is running in gdb I get a callstack that goes to where the exception was thrown.

Comment: At the point the exception is caught (by the unhandled exception catcher), that _is_ the call stack, since the one for `main` was unwound.  Can you look at the contents of `pPtrs`?  There might be an address in there.

Comment: But why is the stack being unwound when the exception is not caught? This makes the error report totally useless.

Comment: Because MS decided to unwind the stack while looking for a handler.  When no handler is found, `std::terminate` is called.  There should be useful data with the `pPtrs` value to `__CxxUnhandledExceptionFilter` but it has been a long time since I've had to look at one of these.

Comment: So how can I debug the crash when it is difficult to attach the debugger?

Comment: Run your program in the debugger in Visual Studio. It's that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trick to get to the "original" stack of the SEH exception. When kernel terminates the program (this is what your stack shows), it still saves the context record of original stack. This article describes how to get to this record using WinDBG: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/313109/how-to-find-the-problem-exception-stack-when-you-receive-an-unhandlede

If you expect to do this often, you can probably write a WinDBG macro for this.

Comment: Any idea how to get visual Studio to do the same thing?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You could get real stack address from UnresolvedExceptionFilter params, but I know no way to change .ecx in VS. There are rumors, that `Immediate` window in VS supports some WinDBG commands, but this is not true. WinDBG is not that difficult, you just need to provide symbols (Ctrl+S) and learn a couple of commands.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing two Microsoft products, Windows and Visual Studio.

Windows Error Reporting deals with Win32 errors, such as unhandled SEH (natove) exceptions. The Visual Studio CRT is responsible for `std::range_error`.

You're proposing a Windows Error Reporting setting that affects the CRT. That can't work. Windows Error Reporting can't even assume a Microsoft CRT is present.

Instead, approach this from the CRT side. The relevant function in the CRT is `std::set_terminate(&your_handler)`

[edit]
Since you want to break into the debugger (which is a Windows thing, not CRT) you'd call [FatalExit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679337(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: And what code should I put into my handler to trap the point of failure? TBH I was hoping an uncaught exceprion would crash as I abort was called at the place the exception was thrown.

Comment: @doron: Added `FatalExit`. But there's also `DebugActiveProcess` - a bit less fatal; I can't tell what works best for you.

Comment: The thing is that I am using WER to collect crash reports from the field. I cannot install a debugger or run debug APIs. I just want a clean crash at tge source of tge error so that I can fix it.

Comment: @doron: Using Microsoft's backend to collect crash reports? In that case look into the [WER functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513635(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I am not having any issue triggering WER (it happens automatically on any crash (abort or access violation). My problem is by the time we get to the uncaught exception handler, we have already unwound the stack and lost all detail of with the exception was thrown in the first place. By contrast, a normal access violation crashes on the spot with and WER then reports the exact state of the application.

Comment: @doron: that's why I wondered whether you might benefit from triggering WER directly, from your terminate handler.